# How can I use Laravel 3 bunbles in laravel 4 if it doesn't have any composer support?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I'm currently working in a project which requires excel export facility. I've found couple of laravel 3 bundles but as Laravel 4 dropped the bundle facility so If I want to use those bundle in laravel 4 how can I do this if it has no composer support?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bunbles! Sorry, couldn't resist.

Answer (score 0):

Why restrict yourself to Laravel bundles? Pick any composer package from packagist.org!

https://packagist.org/search/?q=excel

Comment: Thanks I searched before posting this but I'm confused about packages which is not for l4. Will symphony package work on l4?

Comment: Laravel itself uses a bunch of symphony packages, they definitely can work. I guess there could be a few badly coded packages here and there, but I'm sure you can easily find a nice excel package in there.